# Symfony PHPUnit WebTestCase with RenderController

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I have implemented this test in my app

```
public function testHome()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

It fails because of a render controller in my twig

```
{% extends 'base-pages.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
    <main>
        {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AppController::futureEvents')) }}
        {{ include('includes/popular-places.html.twig') }}
        {{ include('includes/news-event.html.twig') }}
        {{ include('includes/call-section.html.twig') }}
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

The Controller Rendered:

```
public function futureEvents()
{
    $events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('includes/events-home-list.html.twig', [
        'events' => $events,
    ]);
}
```

The error:

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) App\Tests\Controller\HomeControllerTest::testHome Failed asserting
>   that 500 matches expected 200.
>
> /var/www/html/app-web/tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php:15

Why does that happen? Is there a way to handle renderController in a Web Test Case?

Comment: What is the actual error? put the following in your test: $client->getResponse()->getContent(); die; Then run it with phpunit tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php > web/debugTest.html to view the results in a output file.

Comment: For debugging tests I always use $this->assertContains('StringForSureNotInResponse', $client->getResponse()->getContent()); This will show you the returned HTML. You could also search inside var/logs/test.log for 500 to find out what's wrong.

Comment: "Is there a way to handle renderController" -- could you clarify your intent? You would like to see actual error? Or mock the `futureEvents`?

Comment: I have found It. it's because of the `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class)->findAll();` How can I mock that in a WebTestCase?

Comment: What is the actual error you get when this method is executed?

Comment: I don't have any error in my web page. I just get this error in my Web test case. The error is written in my post. `phpunit tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php > web/debugTest.html` does not give me more informations

Comment: mocking calls to doctrine is quite possible (though it would be better to have that part wrapped and mock the wrapper instead), just create a mock of a wrapper and put it inside the container in `setUp` of the testcase. Also possible to mock doctrine itself, but that's not really productive because you'll need to create a whole chain of mocks for all those `->getThis` and `->getThat`. You can also expose exceptions for testing purposes -- make ExceptionListener and just rethrow exception if not `HttpException`. Just bind the listener only in the test config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. According to this doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests

You have to add a env in the php section in your `phpunit.xml.dist`.

```
<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:root@localhost/app" />
```